# what s the different between selector > selector and selector selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I was wondering which is the different between:

```
.myClass/DomElement .myotherclassinsidethatelement
```

and

```
.myClass/DomElement > .myotherclassinsidethatelement
```

the both select the myotherclassinsidethatelement class elements inside my .myClass/DomElement
or I missed something?

Comment: > selects immediate children of element and not all elements on page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.myClass/DomElement > .myotherclassinsidethatelement` selects only the direct children of the parent class.

So:

```
<div class='myClass'>
    <div class='someOther'>
        <div class='myotherclassinsidethatelement'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this case, the `>` version won't select it.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/RRv7u/1/

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

The previous answer I gave was incorrect.  I was under the impression that inheritance and nesting were the same thing, but they are not.  If anyone else had this impression, here is a resource explaining what nesting is:

http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/grouping/

Here is another explaining what specificity is:

http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/specificity/

And here is a final link explaining specificity and inheritance:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/07/css-specificity-and-inheritance/

**Previous answer:**

> The angle bracket in CSS denotes inheritance.  So when you say
>
> ```
> .class1 > .class2 { styles }
> ```
>
> You're saying that the styles you're about to apply for class2 are
>   only going to be applied when class2 is a child of class1.

Comment: It doesn't denote inheritance. It denotes a parent-child relationship between two elements. Inheritance is a different concept entirely, and can apply to both `.class1 .class2` and `.class1 > .class2`.

Comment: @BoltClock Thank you for pointing that out.  I thought they were the same thing.